# Compiling kernels, writing drivers, etc

Tags: discussion

This question as one in an example ...

[raspberry pi booting failed on custom kernel](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3500/raspberry-pi-booting-failed-on-custom-kernel)

I know there are some Linux people here but is it really on topic for Raspberry Pi? I mean it would get more attention at Ubuntu SE where you have a horde of custom kernel compiler- just because its Debian for Pi does not really mean it's about the Raspberry.

We had a question about installing FreeBSD on the Pi - the answers where pointing to OTHER sites that are working on the ports and whatever we answer could end up wrong very quickly.

Should the question in "question" be moved over to a Linux Q&A. I doubt it will get any answers here.

Another example:

[Editing Quirks for a USB driver](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3487/editing-quirks-for-a-usb-driver)

Umm? What...

Answer (score 4):

Compiling a kernel can be heavily dependant on the architecture of the target platform. In our special, bespoke situation, kernel compilation will be different to more generic hardware.

I believe these are on topic and past experience compiling for the Pi will help answers.

Comment: As far as the Kernel is concerned, the Raspberry Pi is no more a *special, bespoke, situation* than any other motherboard.  What is special is that it costs £30 (not £300) and has plenty of hype ;-)

Comment: IF you say so . I wish I knew how to answer that question - It might be unanswered for a loooong time.

Comment: @ppumkin The problem with that question is that the answer could be one of a million different problems. That will still be the case wherever it is posted.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed... Generally I think customizing kernels (even if for a RasPi) belong elsewhere - unless the customization relates to a specific RasPi feature